# Does Spotlight keep a search history?

Tags: macos, spotlight, search

Occasionally, I use Spotlight to quickly compute some expression because I'm too lazy to do it in my head, on paper, or fire up some program. Sometimes I would like to view the result again, but when hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> again, it has disappeared. I'm not sure if this happens only when you search for something else in the meantime or also after some period of time.

The question is, can I somehow cycle back through my previous searches?

System info: **OSX 10.10.4**

Answer (score 5):

I don't think Spotlight keeps a search history. I have confirmed this with numerous web searches. Sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: Allan, in this case it's appropriate and your boilerplate comment (atypically) isn't.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not.  That might be a useful feature.  You can go to http://www.apple.com/feedback/ and click on "macOS" and give feedback/make your suggestion.